# JNI Uncaught exception of type <unknown> ...how does this happen?

Tags: java, exception, java-native-interface

I have some Java code which invokes C++ code, and the C++ code turns around and calls Java, all via JNI.  We were getting the notorius "hs_err_pidXXXX.log", which, strangely enough, was occurring when we invoked `JNIEnv_::GetMethodID(myJniEnv->GetObjectClass(anException), "printStackTrace", "()V")` on the currently pending exception!  So we added:

```
if ((javaException = getJniEnv()->ExceptionOccurred()) != NULL)
{
   jniEnv->ExceptionDescribe();
   .... <other exception handling code> ...
}
```

...after each time we call JNI to try and uncover what exception was occurring.  The result of ExceptionDescribe() was:

```
Uncaught exception of type <unknown>
```

How does this happen?  The `anException` value above came straight from a JNI call to `anException = myJniEnv->ExceptionOccurred()`, wich should yield a throwable, right?  I should be able to print a stack trace on a throwable without JNI crashing, I would think.  Anyone ever run across something like this before?

Comment: Did you try to rethrow the exception after ExceptionDescribe?

Comment: @Sergey We weren't rethrowing the exception via JNI in our code, but if I add a env->ThrowNew() after ExceptionDescribe(), it crashes in the ThrowNew() instead.  However, we can invoke `jclass exceptionClass = env->GetObjectClass(anException);` and print out the jclass of the exception, which is a non-null pointer value.

Comment: Do you know what exception is being thrown by the function you are calling in java?

Comment: @jogabonito Unfortunately, we'd love to know what it is, but, as you see, ExceptionDescribe() says "type <unknown>".  Most of the other methods we've tried to invoke on the thrown exception yield a "fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment" crash.

Comment: What I meant was, if you have access to the java code which is throwing the exception you could use that info for further debugging. My point is if you can isolate the error happening, call some other function in java and in that function throw a dummy exception. Then from your jni, if you are still getting  the same error, then you are potentially looking at some stack corruption earlier in the code

Comment: Have you tried running with -Xcheck:jni?

Comment: Excellent Rickard!  This, together with Black Panda's advice helped us track it down.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like a memory corruption issue, possibly because of Java local references which have already been cleaned up.  Try adding some or all of the following options to your Java command line (or JVM creation arguments in C/C++):

```
  -verbose:jni
  -verbose:gc
  -Xcheck:jni
```

Probably the most interesting of these is –Xcheck:jni (See the Command-line docs).  This will add a bunch of checks for things like using already-deleted local references, and throw an exception at the point the error is detected, instead of much further down in your program when the memory has already been corrupted.  Once you get a java exception at the original source of the error, it should be much easier to use a debugger (like gdb for finding the C++ crash location) or the java stack trace to find exactly where the error happens and hopefully pinpoint the exact object that’s causing the issue.

I learned this from our resident JNI Warrior at work ;)

Comment: Excellent!  After adding these options to our JVM invocation, the application started dying much sooner with the exception "FATAL ERROR in native method: Bad global or local ref passed to JNI", which we were able to track down fairly quickly to a local JNI reference that was (likely) being freed and invoked several times again (26 times!) before finally crashing with the <unknown> exception.  The <unknown> exception was a red herring.

Comment: FYI, the Command-line docs can be found here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html